# Sequence equality of object arrays containing two dimensional object arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, equals

I wanted to code a function doing something with an input `object[,]` and returning an `object[]` whose elements are `object[,]`'s. I just coded something stupid for a start with no input to first set up tests, and then I will properly code the function :

```
public static class TestData
{
    public static object[,] Island1()
    {
        object[,] res = new object[3, 2];
        res[0, 0] = 1;
        res[0, 1] = 0;
        res[1, 0] = 1;
        res[1, 1] = 1;
        res[2, 0] = 1;
        res[2, 1] = 0;
        return res;
    }
}

public class ComponentsFinder
{
    public object[] GetIslands()
    {
        return  new object[]{TestData.Island1()};
    }
}
```

and the test :

```
[TestClass]
public class TestCompomentsFinder
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void FirstTest()
    {
        object[,] island1 = TestData.Island1();
        object[] expected = new object[] {island1};
        object[] actual = new ComponentsFinder().GetIslands();
        bool res = actual.SequenceEqual(expected);
        Assert.IsTrue(res);
    }
}
```

This test fails and I know why : even if both `object[]`'s contain only one `object` representing an `object[,]` that represents the same "matrix", they do not point to the same array, hence the failure of the test.

Would I have a real class `C` instead of `object[,]` it wouldn't be a problem as I would make `C` implement `IEquatable` properly, and the `Equals` override would then be called by `SequenceEquals` and the test would be ok.

But here I don't have a class, so what should I do ? Should I really wrap everything in classes or is there another way to test the equality of my `object[]`'s (which amounts to know to test equality of `object[,]`'s in the sense of having same dimensions and same respective coefficients, the coefficients of my `object[,]`'s are type implementing `IEquatable`) ?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct on why `SequenceEqual()` fails. Arrays in C# are reference types, which means when you compare them you get *reference* equality, which means the CLR checks to see if they are literally the same object in memory (the two `object[,]`s are different objects in memory.)

In addition, `SequenceEqual()` is iterating through your outermost `object[]`'s elements, but it will not reach into those arrays's contents to iterate over the inner `object[,]`.

You need *value* equality, so that you can compare the values of the objects rather than their references.

However, since you're using `object`s for everything, you're not going to get value equality, even if the objects are actually `ints`. See this example from the C# interactive window:

```
> object object1 = 1;
> object object2 = 1;
> object1 == object2
false
> (int)object1 == (int)object2
true
```

You'll need to cast the individual values back into `int`s before you can do a proper comparison on them. I would recommend using `int` arrays anyway, just for better type safety (and probably a tiny bit better performance from not performing a bunch of boxing conversions.)

All that being said, the general approach would be to iterate over every individual item and compare them individually. If they're `int`s in `object[,]` arrays, make sure to cast them (`(int)`) first. As for how you implement this comparison, you have several options.

You can implement your own containing class, as you've already mentioned. In that case you could override/implement interfaces to provide the functionality you need. You can also implement a standalone helper method (something like `public void ArrayCompare(object[,] arr1, object[,] arr2)`, for instance.)

I implemented an example as an extension method, which will allow you to use either `ArrayExtension.ArrayCompare(actual, expected)` or `actual.ArrayCompare(expected)` to use it.

```cs
public static class ArrayExtension
    {
        public static bool ArrayCompare(this object[,] arr1, object[,] arr2)
        {
            if (arr1.Rank != arr2.Rank) return false;

            var numDims = arr1.Rank;
            for(var i = 0; i < numDims; i++)
                if (arr1.GetLength(i) != arr2.GetLength(i))
                    return false;

            for(var j = 0; j < numDims; j++)
            {
                var dimLength = arr1.GetLength(j);
                for(var k = 0; k < dimLength; k++)
                    if ((int)arr1[j, k] != (int)arr2[j, k])
                        return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```